# What kind of action cameras work in very low temperatures?

Tags: action, cold, extreme-sports

I'm looking to research on mounted cameras on supersonic planes, sounding rockets and what cameras can survive the flight as temperatures go below upto -50 C. The range I'm looking at is about -25 to -50 C, what still functions without much worries and if there are things needed for them to work at such temperatures.

Edit: To clarify, we're working on an object that will be heading to the high altitudes and there's a point at 10 km altitude where temperatures go down to -50 C . We'd like footage  at a decent fps, but we're willing to sacrifice it in case of poor performance at low temperatures. Batteries will not be a problem as they will be externally managed during the flight and can go to lower temperatures. We'd like no distortion and sufficient changes in exposure for various light brightness as the object travels through layers of atmosphere.

Comment: Nothing off the shelf probably, because batteries only work down to -20°C unless you use some lead batteries

Comment: Use something very low in energy consumption and power it from suitable double layer capacitors, or something purely mechanical (but lubricants and films still get kinda stiff too!), or... heat the camera (by electrical heating, or chemical heating, or waste heat from your vehicle...)...

Comment: Is that -25°C to 50°C, or do you really mean -25°C to -50°C?

Comment: When you say, "action cameras," do you have a minimum shutter speed in mind? Do you have any resolution requirements? What about lenses and focal lengths? Are you photographing parts of equipment up close through this journey or turning around and aiming at the ground? What are your overall size dimensions for the camera and lens? How quickly will the camera be subject to going from ground ambient temps to negative degrees? (are you worrying about condensation?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're looking for a video camera on a site that is devoted to still photography.

Comment: Hey @Hueco, I appreciate the answers and I wasn't aware that photography stack was only for still photography. I appreciate all the help provided and apologise for asking the question here.

Comment: @Rajath no worries and good luck in your search!

Comment: @RajathPai There is a sister site for video questions: [https://video.stackexchange.com/](https://video.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MichaelClark Thank you, I will move teh question there or could some moderator do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sounding rockets, just use an insulated enclosure with the lens sticking out -- flight time is short, and thermal inertia should keep the camera working. A hand-warmer containing iron filings and salt water might keep it warmer, if need be. Since these heaters require oxygen, they'll slow in less-dense atmosphere, where the need is less because of low thermal conductivity.

Supersonic *air*craft have the opposite problem: *heating* due to air resistance, so you still need thermal isolation.

L. Paul Verhage has an *excellent* [series of articles on near-space](http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/contributor/l_paul_verhage) science, including photography using a variety of cameras (Raspberry Pi NoIR camera in Sep/Oct Nuts & Volts magazine).

Comment: Just go search Amazon deals. Always discount brand "Go" cameras there. Specific gear recommendation is pretty much off-topic.